# Default value in case class, Play Form

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following case class:

```
case class User(id:String = UUID.random().toString, name:String)
```

And the following creation form :

```
val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> text
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )
```

But then the Form is complaining about the apply / unapply function not having enough arguments (the id is missing). Is there any workaround in order not to rewrite all the apply / unapply functions of the case classes and using the default value of the case class ?

Of course this is an example, and my real case is more complex with nested lists of case classes so I would really like to use the 'automatic' case class mapping !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend on @m-z's solution, and `transform` the ignored value to produce a random `UUID` every time:

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "id" -> ignored(()).transform[String](
      _ => UUID.random().toString,
      _ => ()),
    "name" -> text
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

Also, although you have remarked that you don't to rewrite the `apply` and `unapply`, I think in some cases it might still be a possibility as well:

```
val userForm2 = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text
  )(n => User(name = n))(u => User.unapply(u).map(_._2))
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir !!! I used the second solution, which is quite verbose, but remains clean and respect my odd constraint to use the default value from my case class ! Thanks a lot once again !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ignored`:

```
val userForm = Form(
   mapping(
     "id" -> ignored(UUID.random()),
     "name" -> text
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's going to be the same UUID for each request... So it's not a good fit for my case :/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a random and meaningless UUID as a default ID, I like to use an `Option[String]` for model classes; e.g.:

```
case class User(id:Option[String], name:String)
```

Then you can use the `optional` mapping:

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "id" -> optional(text),
    "text" -> text,
  )
)
```

and `fold` (or `match`, whatever you like) on the `id` when the form is submitted back to you, perhaps generating the UUID at that time.

Benefits of doing it this way:

- It's completely obvious whether a form has been populated from defaults
- You can re-use the form for "update my profile"-type operations where the ID is populated

Comment: but then it's a design flaw because it would become possible for the users of my api to specify their own id, which might not be the desired behaviour